# Reporting services subscription reports errors, but logs don't give details

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, data-driven

Where can I find more detail about my subscription errors.

I have a data driven subscription, showing status:

Done: 24 processed of 24 total; 24 errors.

but my trace file ReportServerService__xxxxx.log does not show any errors.  It does show the subscription ran, but just no errors.

My server DefaultTraceSwitch set to 3 and also tried 4

I understand that the other log files used in 2005 have been consolidated into the ReportServerService__xxxxx.log file.

Comment: Update: The root cause in this case appeared to be that the SMTP service had stopped, however this was still not mentioned in the logs.

If you have this issue, check your SMTP service is still running!

Answer (score 1):

You might try running the Profiler Trace to see if you can identify any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't really reveal anything - the reports ran fine if I ran them manually, using parameters I pulled from the subscription query.